# xcode - detect user action when during push notifications authorization

Tags: ios, push-notification

Developing an app with push notifications, I need to know when user tap one of two button (Don't allow, allow) during push notifications authorization.

Is there any delegate to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The callback will be made upon calling `-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]`. The settings the user has granted to the application will be passed in as the second argument.

If you want to see if the user declined the option you can check if `!notification.types` as such:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    // Make sure we check for user permission for location
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
    if (!notificationTypes.types) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You need to enable notifications for this functionality to work." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tx. I tryed it but I need to know when user choose on of two option in the notificationa uthorization alertview. didRegisterUserNotificationSettings is fired when the message appear and  notificationTypes.types is valido only if user has autorized or not the notification

Comment: If !notificationTypes.types then they pressed "Don't allow". if notificationTypes.types then they pressed "allow".

Comment: I need to know when  user press "allow" or  "not allow".

Comment: Yes, I get that. The answer can be inferred from what the value of  notificationTypes.types is. Do you need some further help understanding this or do I need some understanding your question? The code above will let you know whether the user pressed "allow" or "not allow".